# Are there a kind of monopods available which have a minimum height of 10 cm?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, monopod

I like to shoot from the ground level, usually. Google mostly showed me the monopods with minimum height of some 30 cm.

Are there some monopods which are flexible and at the same time can be actually made to sit on the ground?

Comment: I may be wrong, but in my experience Monopods are only stable when you can hold them (so your legs become the other two legs to the monopods one).  At less than 20-30cm I can't see how you'd hold it stable.  I'd go for a beanbag.

Comment: what is the actual problem (or problems) you're trying to solve? I doubt you're going to find a product exactly as you describe, but perhaps there is some other substitute that can do what you require.

Comment: @djangodude actually, I didn't wish to carry many pods outdoors, hence was looking for all in one.

Comment: OK...I still don't think you're going to find a single monopod that can act as a full-size monopod and collapse down to 10cm. That would require so many segments as to make it extremely wobbly when fully extended. BUT: you could probably fashion your own 10cm 'pod out of some lightweight material (PVC pipe or similar hollow tubing with a cap + 1/4" 20 TPI screw for the mount) that would not be too burdensome to carry outdoors. You could probably even attach it to your main monopod with a velcro strap or rubber band.

Comment: @djangodude Alright, I didn't know that these kind of monopods don't exist, thanks.

Comment: To get a monopod that is a minimum of 10cm thats a normal monopod height when fully exntended it would probably need to be around 30cm wide or more at the base

Comment: @Dreamager: Either that, or with such thin segment walls that it would probably flex a foot or more under a normal SLR camera load. I figure you'd need about 20 segments to go from 10 cm to 150 cm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Would a GorillaPod work for you? I know you said monopod but when you are getting down to 10cm, it hardly seems to matter if it is 1 leg or 3. This image is from the JOBY site, they make them.

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes, these things are awesome - I have one for my pocket cam and a slightly larger one for my micro-4/3 camera.

Comment: This picture looks like they just landed and humanity is screwed.

Comment: I already know about gorillapod. Don't want that. It can't be lenghtend up and it has three legs. I am talking about monopods.

Comment: I'm trying to visualize where you would need a monopod at 10cm that couldn't be satisfied with some other device. Carry a real monopod for height, use the other device for low down...

Comment: actually, carruing two devices in parks, office etc isn't comforable. Don't they make any small monopods?

Comment: Lets design such a device. 10cm max height. We'll allow 1cm for the mount, so that gives us 9cm per sliding element. Lets be generous, 4 sliding elements. 9x4=36 plus the 1 for the mount. That's a 37cm (14 inch) max height. I think the market for such a device would be very small.

Comment: I am talking about min height, not max height. I am talking about a flexible monopod.

Comment: "when you are getting down to 10cm, it hardly seems to matter if it is 1 leg or 3." I get your point. I think you are correct.

Answer (score 10):

If you want stability at that height, I would suggest a camera bean bag: http://lifehacker.com/5601668/craft-a-diy-camera-bean-bag-for-on+the+go-stability

There are commercial ones available too but a DIY is just as good.

As an added bonus, you can use them to stabilize a shot from, say, inside your car on a halfway lowered window.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is something like the GorillaPod and its sister products from Joby. http://joby.com/

They make flexible pods that you can use on ground level as well as having articulated arms so you can wrap the legs around different things like tree limbs.

Comment: gorillapods can't be stretched. don't want that. it has 3 legs too.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem simple and cheap enough to make one. (I have not done this, but I have made other camera mounts before).

Buy a length of threaded rod to match your camera, typically 1/4-20. Cut the rod to the desired length (i.e., 10cm), and clean any burrs on the ends. If you don't have tools, some hardware stores may be willing to cut it for you.

Screw the rod into your tripod mount, and call it a monopod!

Depending on how you use it, you might add a washer and a wingnut to more securely attach it to the camera, and add other features as you desire:

- Several jammed nuts in the middle to add grip
- A rubber foot
- Cover the shaft with heat-shrink tubing

You make several at different lengths to make up for a lack of adjustment. I wouldn't make them too long, as the rod will bend more easily, and it could put stress on the camera's threads. I'd expect it to be OK up to about 30cm.

At most US hardware stores, $10 should by a few feet of rod and a handful of washers and nuts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in Bean Bags, take a look at the one listed below. Available in India and works well.

http://www.toehold.in/products/dimbu.php